# Are there projects/initiatives to put "troubleshooting wizards" in Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: application-development, libreoffice

Apparently, [since 1992](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83800/history-first-use-of-wizards) Microsoft has added many troubleshooting wizards to the Help System in Windows and Microsoft Applications.

Linux Distributions have similar task-oriented series of dialogs, but I think mainly for installation of the operating system.

However, there are also "troubleshooting wizards" which are more complex than installation+configuration wizards. The tasks are are nonlinear with respect to time, and behind each decision there needs to be a little table of decision alternatives with probabilities or likelihoods assigned. I've heard that these Wizards are based on Bayesian Networks and Probabilistic Graphs.

Have there been any efforts by the desktop-environment communities, or by academic researchers, to come up with a similar system for Linux Applications? Or a "Linux Help System?"

(Maybe Libreoffice has troubleshooting wizards.)

I'm not asking for examples here (answers still welcome), but more for frameworks or design guidelines. Or have communities decided at some point to NOT use the Wizard paradigm of Human-Computer Interaction?

Comment: Linux is not windows and windows uses "troubleshooting wizards" IMO primarily because their code is closed source. In Linux you can review the source code but in general most programs give relevant error messages which you then read . If you have problems google or ask on the forums. Some servers have programs to test configuration files for example.

Comment: I never did have much luck from the Microsoft wizards, but I agree that a troubleshooting wizard can be very helpful when it works, especially if the wizard is written by a community of experts.  It would be nice to see wizards like that, especially if we want Linux and Ubuntu to spread.

Comment: Personally, I can't remember a single occasion that a troubleshooting wizard was of *any* use to me, not on Windows, not on Mac, not on Ubuntu. Better use a site like this...

Comment: After 17 views  there were 4 close votes ... I've kind of expected that. Maybe I have to ask this at ux.SE ...wanted to try here first.

Comment: My guess is you will have similar results as the question is somewhat vague and asking for speculation.